# playing audio file during fetch react js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, audio-streaming, fetch-api

I have a node.js API which returns music file path on API call.

> my.api.com/musics/1

I can get audio file and then play it with audio.play() function

```
const playAudio = async (id) => {
    try {
      const response = await axiosClient.get(`my.api.com/musics/${id}`)
      const mp3 = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'audio/mp3' })
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(mp3)
      const audio = new Audio(url)
      audio.load()
      await audio.play()
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('play audio error: ', e)
    }
}
```

the problem is that I have to wait for the 10mb mp3 file to fully download and then play it. which is so bad on slow connections.
I want to play the music as it is being fetched. can I do that only in client side and if yes how?
I wanted to try this: [socket.io-stream](https://apiko.com/blog/audio-file-streaming-in-js/)
but I'm not sure if it is the right way to do this. my goal is something like YouTube Music music player.

**the above code is not a working one.(it's not what I want) the api only returns file path.**